# VB Design View not showing buttons and labels

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I made a new project and added the form1.vb and form1.desinger.vb form another project to the new project(was working at another computer and saved the two source to usb moved to home computer and thought i could just add the two source files from my usb to the project and it would work.) now my design view does not showing any buttons or labels; but the code is still there and when i run the program it still works(i can see the form with all controls). I am unable though to use design view to update the properties of the controls. Would like to be able to see buttons and labels back in design view to edit.
here is the form1.designer.vb code:

```
    <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
    Partial Class Form1
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.GroupBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
    Me.txtAdultSold = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.txtAdultPrice = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Label2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.GroupBox2 = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
    Me.txtChildSold = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.txtChildPrice = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Label4 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.Label3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.GroupBox3 = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
    Me.txtTotalGross = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.txtChildSalesGross = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.txtAdultSalesGross = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Label7 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.Label6 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.Label5 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.GroupBox4 = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
    Me.txtTotalNet = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.txtChildSalesNet = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.txtAdultSalesNet = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Label10 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.Label9 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.Label8 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.btnCalucateTicketRev = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.btnClear = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.btnExit = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.GroupBox1.SuspendLayout()
    Me.GroupBox2.SuspendLayout()
    Me.GroupBox3.SuspendLayout()
    Me.GroupBox4.SuspendLayout()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'GroupBox1
    '
    Me.GroupBox1.AutoSize = True
    Me.GroupBox1.Controls.Add(Me.txtAdultSold)
    Me.GroupBox1.Controls.Add(Me.txtAdultPrice)
    Me.GroupBox1.Controls.Add(Me.Label2)
    Me.GroupBox1.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
    Me.GroupBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HotTrack
    Me.GroupBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 22)
    Me.GroupBox1.Name = "GroupBox1"
    Me.GroupBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(236, 122)
    Me.GroupBox1.TabIndex = 0
    Me.GroupBox1.TabStop = False
    Me.GroupBox1.Text = "Adult Ticket Sales"
    '
    'txtAdultSold
    '
    Me.txtAdultSold.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(114, 59)
    Me.txtAdultSold.Name = "txtAdultSold"
    Me.txtAdultSold.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.txtAdultSold.TabIndex = 2
    '
    'txtAdultPrice
    '
    Me.txtAdultPrice.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(114, 27)
    Me.txtAdultPrice.Name = "txtAdultPrice"
    Me.txtAdultPrice.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.txtAdultPrice.TabIndex = 1
    '
    'Label2
    '
    Me.Label2.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
    Me.Label2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(38, 59)
    Me.Label2.Name = "Label2"
    Me.Label2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(69, 13)
    Me.Label2.TabIndex = 1
    Me.Label2.Text = "Tickets Sold:"
    '
    'Label1
    '
    Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
    Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 27)
    Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
    Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(85, 13)
    Me.Label1.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Label1.Text = "Price per Ticket:"
    '
    'GroupBox2
    '
    Me.GroupBox2.AutoSize = True
    Me.GroupBox2.Controls.Add(Me.txtChildSold)
    Me.GroupBox2.Controls.Add(Me.txtChildPrice)
    Me.GroupBox2.Controls.Add(Me.Label4)
    Me.GroupBox2.Controls.Add(Me.Label3)
    Me.GroupBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HotTrack
    Me.GroupBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(274, 22)
    Me.GroupBox2.Name = "GroupBox2"
    Me.GroupBox2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(234, 122)
    Me.GroupBox2.TabIndex = 1
    Me.GroupBox2.TabStop = False
    Me.GroupBox2.Text = "Child Ticket Sales"
    '
    'txtChildSold
    '
    Me.txtChildSold.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(108, 51)
    Me.txtChildSold.Name = "txtChildSold"
    Me.txtChildSold.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.txtChildSold.TabIndex = 4
    '
    'txtChildPrice
    '
    Me.txtChildPrice.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(108, 20)
    Me.txtChildPrice.Name = "txtChildPrice"
    Me.txtChildPrice.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.txtChildPrice.TabIndex = 3
    '
    'Label4
    '
    Me.Label4.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
    Me.Label4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(31, 58)
    Me.Label4.Name = "Label4"
    Me.Label4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(69, 13)
    Me.Label4.TabIndex = 1
    Me.Label4.Text = "Tickets Sold:"
    '
    'Label3
    '
    Me.Label3.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
    Me.Label3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(15, 20)
    Me.Label3.Name = "Label3"
    Me.Label3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(85, 13)
    Me.Label3.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Label3.Text = "Price per Ticket:"
    '
    'GroupBox3
    '
    Me.GroupBox3.AutoSize = True
    Me.GroupBox3.Controls.Add(Me.txtTotalGross)
    Me.GroupBox3.Controls.Add(Me.txtChildSalesGross)
    Me.GroupBox3.Controls.Add(Me.txtAdultSalesGross)
    Me.GroupBox3.Controls.Add(Me.Label7)
    Me.GroupBox3.Controls.Add(Me.Label6)
    Me.GroupBox3.Controls.Add(Me.Label5)
    Me.GroupBox3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HotTrack
    Me.GroupBox3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 150)
    Me.GroupBox3.Name = "GroupBox3"
    Me.GroupBox3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(236, 152)
    Me.GroupBox3.TabIndex = 2
    Me.GroupBox3.TabStop = False
    Me.GroupBox3.Text = "Gross Ticket Revenue"
    '
    'txtTotalGross
    '
    Me.txtTotalGross.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(120, 99)
    Me.txtTotalGross.Name = "txtTotalGross"
    Me.txtTotalGross.ReadOnly = True
    Me.txtTotalGross.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.txtTotalGross.TabIndex = 5
    '
    'txtChildSalesGross
    '
    Me.txtChildSalesGross.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(117, 59)
    Me.txtChildSalesGross.Name = "txtChildSalesGross"
    Me.txtChildSalesGross.ReadOnly = True
    Me.txtChildSalesGross.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.txtChildSalesGross.TabIndex = 4
    '
    'txtAdultSalesGross
    '
    Me.txtAdultSalesGross.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(117, 21)
    Me.txtAdultSalesGross.Name = "txtAdultSalesGross"
    Me.txtAdultSalesGross.ReadOnly = True
    Me.txtAdultSalesGross.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.txtAdultSalesGross.TabIndex = 3
    '
    'Label7
    '
    Me.Label7.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
    Me.Label7.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopLeft
    Me.Label7.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(6, 98)
    Me.Label7.Name = "Label7"
    Me.Label7.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes
    Me.Label7.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(110, 38)
    Me.Label7.TabIndex = 2
    Me.Label7.Text = "Total Gross Revenue :for Ticket Sales"
    '
    'Label6
    '
    Me.Label6.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label6.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
    Me.Label6.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(19, 59)
    Me.Label6.Name = "Label6"
    Me.Label6.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(95, 13)
    Me.Label6.TabIndex = 1
    Me.Label6.Text = "Child Ticket Sales:"
    '
    'Label5
    '
    Me.Label5.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label5.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
    Me.Label5.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(16, 20)
    Me.Label5.Name = "Label5"
    Me.Label5.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(96, 13)
    Me.Label5.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Label5.Text = "Adult Ticket Sales:"
    '
    'GroupBox4
    '
    Me.GroupBox4.AutoSize = True
    Me.GroupBox4.Controls.Add(Me.txtTotalNet)
    Me.GroupBox4.Controls.Add(Me.txtChildSalesNet)
    Me.GroupBox4.Controls.Add(Me.txtAdultSalesNet)
    Me.GroupBox4.Controls.Add(Me.Label10)
    Me.GroupBox4.Controls.Add(Me.Label9)
    Me.GroupBox4.Controls.Add(Me.Label8)
    Me.GroupBox4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HotTrack
    Me.GroupBox4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(274, 150)
    Me.GroupBox4.Name = "GroupBox4"
    Me.GroupBox4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(234, 137)
    Me.GroupBox4.TabIndex = 3
    Me.GroupBox4.TabStop = False
    Me.GroupBox4.Text = "Net Ticket Revenue"
    '
    'txtTotalNet
    '
    Me.txtTotalNet.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(123, 91)
    Me.txtTotalNet.Name = "txtTotalNet"
    Me.txtTotalNet.ReadOnly = True
    Me.txtTotalNet.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.txtTotalNet.TabIndex = 5
    '
    'txtChildSalesNet
    '
    Me.txtChildSalesNet.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(123, 59)
    Me.txtChildSalesNet.Name = "txtChildSalesNet"
    Me.txtChildSalesNet.ReadOnly = True
    Me.txtChildSalesNet.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.txtChildSalesNet.TabIndex = 4
    '
    'txtAdultSalesNet
    '
    Me.txtAdultSalesNet.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(123, 19)
    Me.txtAdultSalesNet.Name = "txtAdultSalesNet"
    Me.txtAdultSalesNet.ReadOnly = True
    Me.txtAdultSalesNet.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.txtAdultSalesNet.TabIndex = 3
    '
    'Label10
    '
    Me.Label10.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
    Me.Label10.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(6, 91)
    Me.Label10.Name = "Label10"
    Me.Label10.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes
    Me.Label10.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(110, 28)
    Me.Label10.TabIndex = 2
    Me.Label10.Text = "Total Net Revenue :for Ticket Sales"
    '
    'Label9
    '
    Me.Label9.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label9.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
    Me.Label9.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(21, 59)
    Me.Label9.Name = "Label9"
    Me.Label9.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(95, 13)
    Me.Label9.TabIndex = 1
    Me.Label9.Text = "Child Ticket Sales:"
    '
    'Label8
    '
    Me.Label8.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label8.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
    Me.Label8.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(21, 19)
    Me.Label8.Name = "Label8"
    Me.Label8.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(96, 13)
    Me.Label8.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Label8.Text = "Adult Ticket Sales:"
    '
    'btnCalucateTicketRev
    '
    Me.btnCalucateTicketRev.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window
    Me.btnCalucateTicketRev.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat
    Me.btnCalucateTicketRev.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(133, 315)
    Me.btnCalucateTicketRev.Name = "btnCalucateTicketRev"
    Me.btnCalucateTicketRev.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(96, 50)
    Me.btnCalucateTicketRev.TabIndex = 4
    Me.btnCalucateTicketRev.Text = "&Calculate Ticket Revenue"
    Me.btnCalucateTicketRev.UseVisualStyleBackColor = False
    '
    'btnClear
    '
    Me.btnClear.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(235, 315)
    Me.btnClear.Name = "btnClear"
    Me.btnClear.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(74, 50)
    Me.btnClear.TabIndex = 5
    Me.btnClear.Text = "Cl&ear"
    Me.btnClear.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'btnExit
    '
    Me.btnExit.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(316, 315)
    Me.btnExit.Name = "btnExit"
    Me.btnExit.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(74, 50)
    Me.btnExit.TabIndex = 6
    Me.btnExit.Text = "E&xit"
    Me.btnExit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Form1
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(520, 430)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnExit)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnClear)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnCalucateTicketRev)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.GroupBox4)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.GroupBox3)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.GroupBox2)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.GroupBox1)
    Me.Name = "Form1"
    Me.Text = "Theater Revenue"
    Me.GroupBox1.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.GroupBox1.PerformLayout()
    Me.GroupBox2.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.GroupBox2.PerformLayout()
    Me.GroupBox3.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.GroupBox3.PerformLayout()
    Me.GroupBox4.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.GroupBox4.PerformLayout()
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()

End Sub
Friend WithEvents GroupBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
Friend WithEvents GroupBox2 As System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
Friend WithEvents GroupBox3 As System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
Friend WithEvents GroupBox4 As System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
Friend WithEvents Label2 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label4 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label3 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label7 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label6 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label5 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label10 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label9 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label8 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents txtAdultSold As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents txtAdultPrice As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents txtChildSold As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents txtChildPrice As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents txtTotalGross As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents txtChildSalesGross As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents txtAdultSalesGross As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents txtTotalNet As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents txtChildSalesNet As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents txtAdultSalesNet As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents btnCalucateTicketRev As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents btnClear As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents btnExit As System.Windows.Forms.Button
```

End Class

form1.vb code:

```
    Public Class Form1
Dim tickets_Sold_Adult As Integer
Dim ticktes_Sold_Child As Integer
Dim price_Adult As Double
Dim price_Child As Double
Dim totalAdult, totalChild, pretotal As Double
Const profitNet As Double = 0.2

Private Sub txtAdultPrice_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtAdultPrice.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(txtAdultPrice.Text) Then
        price_Adult = txtAdultPrice.Text
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtAdultSold_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtAdultSold.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(txtAdultSold.Text) Then
        tickets_Sold_Adult = txtAdultSold.Text
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtChildPrice_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtChildPrice.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(txtChildPrice.Text) Then
        price_Child = txtChildPrice.Text
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtChildSold_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtChildSold.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(txtChildSold.Text) Then
        ticktes_Sold_Child = txtChildSold.Text
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnCalucateTicketRev_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalucateTicketRev.Click
    totalAdult = price_Adult * tickets_Sold_Adult
    txtAdultSalesGross.Text = Format(totalAdult, "$0.00")
    txtAdultSalesNet.Text = Format(totalAdult * 0.2, "$0.00")
    totalChild = price_Child * ticktes_Sold_Child
    txtChildSalesGross.Text = Format(totalChild, "$0.00")
    txtChildSalesNet.Text = Format(totalChild * 0.2, "$0.00")
    pretotal = (totalAdult + totalChild)
    txtTotalGross.Text = Format(pretotal, "$0.00")
    txtTotalNet.Text = Format(profitNet * pretotal, "$0.00")
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    txtAdultPrice.Clear()
    txtAdultSold.Clear()
    txtChildPrice.Clear()
    txtChildSold.Clear()
    txtAdultSalesGross.Clear()
    txtAdultSalesNet.Clear()
    txtChildSalesGross.Clear()
    txtChildSalesNet.Clear()
    txtTotalGross.Clear()
    txtTotalNet.Clear()
    price_Adult = 0
    price_Child = 0
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: well I have cut n pasted your designer.vb code into VS2010 and your form appears ok in design view . . .

Comment: I figured it out, i was including the designer file with the project when i should only be adding the form1.vb file.

Answer (score -1):

In general the best way to troubleshoot this type of problem is to get both folders (from work and from home) and diff them with a tool like [WinDiff](http://www.grigsoft.com/download-windiff.htm)

This will give you a very clear visual difference between your projects that will teach you all kinds of things.